# Removing whitespace from strings in Prolog

Tags: string, parsing, prolog, whitespace, dcg

I wrote parser in Prolog. I haven't finished yet. It is a part of code. The next step is killing all whitespace in string.

```
parse(Source, Tree) :-  kill_whitespace(Source, CleanInput), % remove whitespaces
                        actual_parse(CleanInput, Tree).

actual_parse(CleanInput, Tree):- phrase(expr(Tree),CleanInput).

expr(Ast) --> term(Ast1), expr_(Ast1,Ast).
expr_(Acc,Ast) --> " + ", !, term(Ast2), expr_(plus(Acc,Ast2), Ast).
expr_(Acc,Ast) --> " - ", !, term(Ast2), expr_(minus(Acc,Ast2), Ast).
expr_(Acc,Acc) --> [].

term(Ast) --> factor(Ast1), term_(Ast1,Ast).
term_(Acc,Ast) --> " * ", !, factor(Ast2), term_(mul(Acc,Ast2),Ast).
term_(Acc,Ast) --> " ** ", !, factor(Ast2), term_(pol(Acc,Ast2),Ast).
term_(Acc,Acc) --> [].

factor(Ast) --> "(", !, expr(Ast), ")".
factor(D)--> [X], { X >= 48 , X=<57 , D is X-48 }.
factor(id(N,E)) --> "x", factor(N), ":=", expr(E), ";".
```

For example:

```
?- parse("x2:=4",T).
    T = id(2, 4)
```

True! But, when I write:

```
?- parse("x2 := 4",T).
false.
```

It must be true as well and it should be a filter: `kill_whitespace(Source, CleanInput)`.

Different solutions are inefficient.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually place a 'skip' non terminal where space can occurs. Such skip usually discards comments as well as any other 'uninteresting' text.

To keep as simpler as possible:

```
% discard any number of spaces
s --> "" ; " ", s.
```

I prefer a short name, to keep the grammar clean. To discard newlines etc.. as well:

```
s --> "" ; (" ";"\t";"\n";"\r"), s.
```

A 'style' note: instead of

```
parse(Source, Tree) :-
   expr(Tree, Source, []).
```

you could consider

```
parse(Source, Tree) :-
   phrase(expr(Tree), Source).
```

Answer (score 1):

well, the easy way is to parse the string and remove whitespace/keep only non-whispace with a [filter predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29). But this requires a second parse.

An other way to fix it is to use your own predicate to "get" characters,
i.e. `foo --> "a".` becomes `foo --> get("a").` where `get//1` is something like:

```
get(X) --> [X].
get(X) --> whitespace, get(X).
```

Comment: A filter make difficult to *preserve* spaces where needed, like inside strings. And there could be also places where spaces are required to separate tokens. To be true the last case isn't handled neither from the skip predicate I proposed...

Comment: @CapelliC indeed. it would be better to tokenize the input and handle all the whitespace/string/etc issues and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of writing a parser is to write it in two stages:

The first stage conducts *lexical analysis* and produces a stream of *tokens*. Whitespace and other "tokens" not significant to the parse (e.g., comments) are discarded at this point.

The second stage conducts the *parse* itself, examining the list of tokens produced by the lexical analyzer.