# Split atom and conserve separators

Tags: list, split, prolog

suppose that I a have an atom which contains some keyN-separators , how I can generate a list that contains list of separate elements

*1000<=N<=5000~ keys/elements*

**Example :**

```
  ?- Atom ='elem1key1elem2key2elem3key1...elemN,keyN',
     split_atom_list(Atom,[key1,key2,keyN],Res_List).

Res_List = [elem1,key1,elem2,key2,...elemN,keyN];
yes
```

Comment: So it takes a list of keys, throws out any key/element pairs not in the original atom, gives all the element/key pairs as separate list element, except the last one. The last one it throws out just the key and keeps the last element? You are also showing `elemN' in quotes, which is the same as without the quotes. Is there significance in that? With or without, in this case, they're the same thing. Perhaps another example would help, just to make sure the pattern is clear.

Comment: Shouldn't the result list of your example be, `Res_List = [elem1,key1,elem2,key2,...elemN,keyN];`? Or are you intentionally dropping the key for the last element?

Comment: @lurker the last element  may be a key

Comment: @lurker up to now I change the predicate atomic_concat_list [@CapelliC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317539/split-atom-using-sicstus-like-atomic-list-concat-3-in-swi) to maintain a single key then finished with other keys recursively, but this is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321084/874024) referred in comments, using built-in predicates that (I think) are available in SICStus:

```
split_atom_list(Atom, Keys, [Res, Key|Res_List]) :-
    aggregate(min(P,(Q,K)), S^(
        member(K, Keys),
        sub_atom(Atom, P,Q,S, K)), min(X,(N,Key))),
    sub_atom(Atom, 0,X,_, Res),
    Z is X+N,
    sub_atom(Atom, Z,_,0, Rest),
    !, split_atom_list(Rest, Keys, Res_List).
split_atom_list(_Atom, _Keys, []).
```

The aggregation looks for the first (leftmost) matching key. You could change the base case to accept any unparsed tail:

```
split_atom_list(Atom, _Keys, [Atom]).
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I have a problem when  I try this query ; `split_atom_list('id0 REF id1 FER id2 REF** id3 FER id4**',[' REF '],Res).
Res = [id0,' REF ','id1 FER id2',' REF '] ?`

Comment: I got other error with this query, `?-split_atom_list('id0<<:id1<id5<<id2<:id6<<:id3<id5:id4',['<<:','<<','<:',':'],Res).
Res = [id0,<<:,'id1<id5',<<,id2,<:,id6,<<:,'id3<id5',:] ? `

Comment: What are the errors ? Maybe the 'grammar' is ambiguous ? Maybe there should be also '<' among separators...

Comment: I  reverse the order of  separators and I get this result ; `| ?- split_atom_list('id0<<:id1<id5<<id2<:id6<<:id3<id5:id4',[:,<,<<,'<<:'],Res).
Res = [id0,<,'',<,'',:,id1,<,id5,<,'',<,id2,<,'',:,id6,<,'',<,'',:,id3,<,id5,:] ? ;
`

Comment: plz can you explain why and how the predicate aggregate works also the^ and min(C,(A,B))

Comment: aggregate (see [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate/3) an example) finds the min key position (P), saving as key length (Q) as well as the key (K) itself. ^ is required to let free the distance from end (S)

Comment: when i try to skipping space inside syntaxe with this [methode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366036/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-prolog) I got an error ? can you adding a sample example to inserting `s/0` inside syntaxe

Comment: well, we are not using a DCG here, so I don't know where I could put the example. Which error ? stack overflow ? beware that two s//0 must **not** be consecutive (for instance joined by non terminals expanding to possible empty string)

Comment: I use this predicate `s --> "" ; " ", s.`,  ident(X),`s`,ident(Y).

Comment: The problem then is ambiguity ? To require at least 1 space you can change to: `s --> " "; " ", s.`, but I would introduce another predicate...

Comment: the predicat  is in the link above(methode) ?

Comment: like `s1 --> "  ";"  ",s.` and `s-->"";"  ",s.`

Comment: or, better, `s1 --> " ", s.`